# Как активировать анимацию после нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В верстке я начинающий и столкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно чтобы свойство `transition` начинало работать сразу, после нажатие на кнопку, а не при наведении (`hover` оставил как пример) как это реализовать? Не исключаю возможность многочисленных костылей, но по другому не знаю как.

```js
One.onclick = function(){
  let display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blockOne')).display;
  if (display == "none"){
      document.getElementById('blockOne').style.display = "block";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('blockOne').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.Nav:hover{
  width: 100px;
}

.Nav{
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 10px; height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px;
  transition: width 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

#blockOne{
  font-family: Junegull;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#One{
  font-family: Junegull;
  font-size: 40px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="One">Надпись</div>
<div id="blockOne">Что-то
   <div class="Nav"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ты можешь посчитать этот ответ бессмысленным, но всё же.
Лучше выучить какой-то фреймворк или хотя бы jquery, там такие задачи быстро решаются. Даже щас можешь посмотреть справочник по jquery, возможно сможешь сходу разобраться.

Comment: Я не против jquery, но как я написал, я начинающий в верстке и хотел бы освоить для начала чистый javascript, другими словами, без нагромождения кода и костылей, мою проблему не решить?

Comment: Я вас понял. На чистом js я не знаю как это выполнить(но это не значит, что это нельзя сделать).

Comment: Все равно спасибо вам.

Comment: @keyframes Вам в помощь

Comment: @Arsen123, Вы даёте совет выучить JQ, потому что знаете пару его методов из доков, но не знаете язык программирования? Я всё правильно понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимация не работает, т.к. стиль применяется до отрисовки элемента и, когда он отрисовывается, у него уже `width:100px`.
Решение, возможно, не очень красивое, но работает :)

```js
let blockOne = document.getElementById('blockOne');
let one = document.querySelector('#One');
let nav = document.querySelector(".Nav")



one.onclick = () => {
    blockOne.style.display == "block" ?       blockOne.style.display = "none" :   blockOne.style.display = "block";
    //пощаем переключение класса в очередь после отрисовки.
    setTimeout(()=>{
      nav.classList.toggle("one-showed")
    }, 0)
}
```

```css
.one-showed {
  width: 100px !important;
}


.Nav{
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 10px; height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#blockOne{
  font-family: Junegull;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none
}

#One{
  font-family: Junegull;
  font-size: 40px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="One">Надпись</div>
<div id="blockOne" style="">Что-то
   <div class="Nav"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное)

Comment: @Den4ik если вдруг логика не очень понятна, то про call stack почитайте.