# Display: none убивает анимацию

Tags: css, css3

```css
.header__button .about__button:after{
    content: "some text ??/????????";

    display: none;

    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 5px;


    color: #222; 
    background: #e3dada;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .2s;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: calc(50% - 200px/2);
}

.header__button .about__button:hover:after{
    top: 55px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Есть блок при наведении на который должен появляться его `:after` и уежжать в низ.Но если изначально поставить `display:none`, а затем через `:hover` ставить его афтеру `display: flex`, то `:transition` не срабатывает и афтер оказываеться сразу в низу без аницамии опускания,если же изначально не устанавливать `dispay: none`, то анимация работает как надо,в чем проблема?

Comment: в display:none - display - не анимируемое свойство

Comment: Здесь ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073657/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83/1073691#1073691