# Возможно ли плавно анимировать с display:none в display:block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли плавно анимировать с display:none в display:block. По факту очень резко появляются элементы и хаотично (то снизу вверх, то наоборот). Хотелось бы чтобы сверху вниз плавно.

Comment: Можно. Смотрите ответ в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073657/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83/1073691#1073691) вопросе

Comment: Я бы пересмотрел вашу верстку, например в `<ul>` могут быть только `<li>`, у вас же еще и дивы.

Comment: Для "спойлеров" я бы вешал слушатель клика на обвертку и использовал делегирование, а искал бы нужный ".active" по атрибуту ```wrapper.querySelector(`.active[data-content="${this.dataset.title}"]`);```.

Comment: на вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1396892/ прыгает изза горизонального скролбара. кусок блока торчит за экраном. фиксить `section {overflow-y:hidden;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анимировать `display` не получится, однако вы можете достичь желаемого эффекта с помощью изменения прозрачности и отступа

```css
an-1{
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate op;
}
an-2{
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate mv;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
}

an-1, an-2{ font-family:Menlo; font-size:50px; }

@keyframes op {
  0% { opacity:0; }   
  100% { opacity:1; }
}

@keyframes mv {
  0% { left: 10px; }  
  100% { left: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<an-1>Hello,</an-1> <an-2>World!</an-2>
```

Также интересных эффектов вы можете добиться с помощью фильтров

```css
an-1{
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate op;
}
an-2{
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate mv;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
}

an-1, an-2{ font-family:Menlo; font-size:50px; }

@keyframes op {
  0% {
     filter:blur(50px) opacity(0);
     -webkit-filter:blur(50px) opacity(0);
  }  
  100% {
     filter:blur(0px) opacity(1);
     -webkit-blur(0px) opacity(1);
  }
}

@keyframes mv {
  0% { left: 10px; }  
  100% { left: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<an-1>Hello,</an-1> <an-2>World!</an-2>
```

Comment: С помощью opacity не могу, потому что элемент будет занимать место и меня будут дырки на странице, когда элемент скрыт.

Comment: @tati да нет же, я же специально показал, как сделать так, чтобы элемент место не занимал) с помощью отступов; можно даже и с помощью негативных отступов (отрицательных)

Comment: Спасибо большое)))))))

Answer (score 2):

### На ответ не претендую, просто хочу внести ясности.

`display` такое свойство, которое никак не анимируется, но многие встречали, допустим в **jQuery**, как кодом анимируют состояние `display`, такими методами как `.show()`/`.hide()`, `.slideUp()`/`.slideDown()` и т.п.

Разберём появление блока на примере `.show()` и `fadeIn()`.

`.fadeIn()` - из `display: none` переведёт блок в нужное состояние `display`, при это плавно отобразив его появление (как при смене `opacity` с `0` на `1`).

А вот `.show()` по сути сделает так же, но ещё и изменит размер.

```js
$('.hidden').delay(1000).show(1000);
$('.hidden1').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000)
```

```css
.hidden, .hidden1 {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="hidden">Секретный текст</span> <span>обычный текст</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="hidden1">Секретный текст</span> <span>обычный текст</span>
</div>
```

Всё дело в том, что они быстро меняют `display: none` на нужный, но мы всё так же не видим блок из-за `opacity`, которое потом и анимируется.

Принцип работы у них следующий:

`.fadeIn()`

1. Получаем какое должно быть состояние `display`
2. Быстро меняем состояние `display`, но не отображаем блок `opacity: 0`
3. Анимируем `opacity` с 0 до 1
4. Финиш.

`.show()`

В целом такой же как и у `.fadeIn()`, но к пункту 2 и 3 добавляем ещё и размер `width`/`height`

---

В целом вы можете решить вопрос и на чистом **CSS**, но без смены статуса, при этом максимально ограничить блок, до его появления, например так:

```css
.fix > span {display: inline-block;}

/* fadeIn() */
.hidden {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: fadeIn 1s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    width: 115.3px;
    height: 1em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* show() */
.hidden1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: show 1s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
  0%, 100% {
    width: inherit;
    height: 1em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">
  <span class="hidden">Секретный текст</span> <span>обычный текст</span>
</div>

<div class="fix">
  <span class="hidden1">Секретный текст</span> <span>обычный текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо)))) Учту в будущем